# TensorFlow: Softmax applied to each entry

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I have a tensor `x` of type `tf.float32` and I would like to apply softmax over all entries. Unfortunately, the built-in function can apply softmax along a specified axis only.

The solution I thought of:

```
e = tf.exp(x)
softmaxed = e / tf.reduce_sum(e)
```

does **not** work - if `x` has too big entries (e.g. 100), then `e` cannot be calculated properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `softmax(x) = softmax(x-c)` for any constant `c` (`exp(-c)` factors out of all the exponentials, and cancels between numerator and demoninator), you can apply the softmax in a numerically stable way by subtracting an appropriate constant.  Subtracting the max over all your entries means all your exponentials will be between 0 and 1, and the result can be computed stably.  Give this a try:

```
max_x = tf.reduce_max(x)
e = tf.exp(x-max_x)
softmaxed = e / tf.reduce_sum(e)
```